# Joomla Submit article redirect to homepage

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have site that user can submit an article in frontend . I have create menu submit article, but when i click it , it redirect to homepage.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The guidelines are here: [Joomla : How to create an article from the front end](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_an_article_from_the_front_end).

Go through below:

1. Your menu item should not have access to only special members if you are submitting content as registered member. In short, you should maintain the access level of the page.
2. There can be some other cases, for which you must need to post the screenshot if any error message shown on the screen to debug. As you know there are many settings, custom code, and tweaks that Joomla CMS allows to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To change the redirection when submitting an article I found it useful to do the following:

Associate the form that enables you to create an article from the frontend to a menu, and then edit the corresponding element of the menu, on the options tab, select the redirection after submission category to where you want it to redirect and that's it. Hope it helps anyone!

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please extend your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and help us to build some awesome content.